# TextAreaFor doesn't show default value (MVC4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to give my TextAreaFor a default value from my database (a certain comment which they can edit). I use the @Value and I can see it in the html code (inspect element), but in the textarea itself it isn't visible.

My code:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.description, new { Value = ViewBag.Description }

ViewBag.Description = adver.description;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textarea` works differently then other input fields in HTML and because of this the `value` attribute doesn't actually do anything that you'd expect.

```
<textarea value="you won't see this">you will see this</textarea>
```

Versus a text field:

```
<input type="text" value="you will see this" />
```

Because of this you need to assign the text that you want to be shown in the textarea to the variable before creating the textarea.

**Edit**

Here's a more complete example for you:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var myDefaultDescription = ""; //Replace with whatever you initialize ViewBag.Description with
    return View(new AdverModel{ description = myDefaultDescription });
}
```

This will cause the model to be initialized in the controller. The `@Html.TextAreaFor()` only uses fields and values from the model object that's passed into the view. The Model variable is read only in the view so you must initialize it in the controller and pass it to the view during the return from the controller.

This will cause that field to auto populate with the default value.

Comment: I get the following error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on Model.description= ViewBag.Description.

I've checked and I put text in ViewBag.Description in the Controller.

Comment: I don't know what your page object is, I assumed you were using the generic Model object but if not you'll need to set whatever object `a` in `a => a.description` is based from to the value of the text. If you are using the `Model` object and you load the page without passing it in via the controller then you'll have to do a `Model = new PageObjectClass()` with `PageObjectClass` being whatever object name you need.

Comment: My model is: `public class AdverModel { [Required] [Display(Name ="Omschrijving")] public object description { get; set; }`. --- Now I in did my viewcontroller `AdverModel ad = new AdverModel(); ad.description = adver.description;` But that didnt do anything.

Comment: I updated my answer to expound on how to do this. It has to be done in the controller if you're not passing an initialized object into the view.